# SKSpriteNode only charge part of the texture color

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

Is it possible to apply a color to an SKSpriteNode texture but only to blend with a certain color of it?

e.g say I had a cube (not 3d but a 2d texture that looks like a cube) and I had the top white, the bottom left blue, and the bottom right red. Could I apply a color and a color blend factor to only change a color of my choosing? e.g either the white, red or blue.

Please note I've only used a cube for simplicity in this example. In a real like scenario the nodes wouldn't be so easily 'chopped' up like a cube face might for the purposes of a workaround. The texture could have part of it left transparent or always white, but there will always be at least one other color on it that shouldn't change (think of it as textures that are part background, part a game object)

Comment: No, you can't target specific colors, you would have to use shaders to achieve your affect,  or use an overlay skspritenode to keep your solid colors

Comment: Brilliant that was really useful info, thanks a lot

Comment: @Knight0fDragon do you want to expand your comment to an answer seen as it solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want to achieve, you have 2 options:

1) Learn how to use `SKShader`:  This unfortunately I cannot help you with because I have a guy that handles this stuff for me, so I have no need to learn shaders extensively.  Basically what you are doing is at the GPU level, targeting certain pixels that you want to allow to change.

2) The more easier approach for the novice user, is to use 2 SKSpriteNodes.  You create your 1st sprite with all of the solid colors you want, then you create a gray scale overlay image for all the pixels you want to change.  You can then apply the `colorBlendFactor` to achieve the effect you want.

Basically:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"fullcolor")
let overlay = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"overlay")
overlay.color = .Red
overlay.zPosition = 1
overlay.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
sprite.addChild(overlay)
```

Comment: Actually went the shader route!

Comment: very nice, the shader is the way to go,  I would post the shader code for people to use it in the future, you could edit my answer or add a new one.